# Robustly retrieve SHA and line content with Git blame (Python3)

Tags: python, git-blame

I'm contributing to a package (Python >= 3.5) that uses `git blame` to retrieve information on files. I'm working on replacing the [GitPython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) dependency with custom code supporting just the small subset of functionality we actually need (and provide the data in the form we actually need).

I found that `git blame -lts` came closest to what I need, namely retrieving the commit SHA and line content for each line in a file. This gives me output like

```
82a3e5021b7131e31fc5b110194a77ebee907955 books/main/docs/index.md  5) Softwareplattform [ILIAS](https://www.ilias.de/), die an zahlreichen
```

I've processed this with

```py
       line_pattern = re.compile('(.*?)\s.*\s*\d\)(\s*.*)')

        for line in cmd.stdout():
            m = line_pattern.match(line)
            if m:
                sha = m.group(1)
                content = m.group(2).strip()
```

which works well. However, that package's maintainer correctly warned that "This might introduce hard to debug errors for very specific groups of users. Probably needs to be heavily unit tested, across multiple OS and GIT versions."

I had come to my approach because I found the output of `git blame --porcelain` somewhat tedious to parse.

```
30ed8daf1c48e4a7302de23b6ed262ab13122d31 1 1 1
author XY
author-mail <XY>
author-time 1580742131
author-tz +0100
committer XY
committer-mail <XY>
committer-time 1580742131
committer-tz +0100
summary Stub-Outline-Dateien
filename home/docs/README.md
        hero: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
82a3e5021b7131e31fc5b110194a77ebee907955 18 18

82a3e5021b7131e31fc5b110194a77ebee907955 19 19
        ---
82a3e5021b7131e31fc5b110194a77ebee907955 20 20

...
```

I don't like the housekeepeing involved in that kind of iteration over string lists.

My question is:

1) should I better use the `--porcelain` output because that is explicitly intended for machine consumption?
2) Can i expect this format to be robust over Git versions and OSes? Can I rely on the assumption that a line starting with a TAB character is the content line, that this is the final line of output for a source line, and that anything after that tab is the original line content?

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing if that's the best solution I gave it a try without waiting for answers here. I assumed the answer to my two questions to be "yes".

The following code can be seen in context here: https://github.com/uliska/mkdocs-git-authors-plugin/blob/6f5822c641452cea3edb82c2bbb9ed63bd254d2e/mkdocs_git_authors_plugin/repo.py#L466-L565

```py
    def _process_git_blame(self):
        """
        Execute git blame and parse the results.

        This retrieves all data we need, also for the Commit object.
        Each line will be associated with a Commit object and counted
        to its author's "account".
        Whether empty lines are counted is determined by the
        count_empty_lines configuration option.

        git blame --porcelain will produce output like the following
        for each line in a file:

        When a commit is first seen in that file:
            30ed8daf1c48e4a7302de23b6ed262ab13122d31 1 2 1
            author John Doe
            author-mail <j.doe@example.com>
            author-time 1580742131
            author-tz +0100
            committer John Doe
            committer-mail <j.doe@example.com>
            committer-time 1580742131
            summary Fancy commit message title
            filename home/docs/README.md
                    line content (indicated by TAB. May be empty after that)

        When a commit has already been seen *in that file*:
            82a3e5021b7131e31fc5b110194a77ebee907955 4 5
                    line content

        In this case the metadata is not repeated, but it is guaranteed that
        a Commit object with that SHA has already been created so we don't
        need that information anymore.

        When a line has not been committed yet:
            0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 1 1 1
            author Not Committed Yet
            author-mail <not.committed.yet>
            author-time 1583342617
            author-tz +0100
            committer Not Committed Yet
            committer-mail <not.committed.yet>
            committer-time 1583342617
            committer-tz +0100
            summary Version of books/main/docs/index.md from books/main/docs/index.md
            previous 1f0c3455841488fe0f010e5f56226026b5c5d0b3 books/main/docs/index.md
            filename books/main/docs/index.md
                    uncommitted line content

        In this case exactly one Commit object with the special SHA and fake
        author will be created and counted.

        Args:
            ---
        Returns:
            --- (this method works through side effects)
        """

        re_sha = re.compile('^\w{40}')

        cmd = GitCommand('blame', ['--porcelain', str(self._path)])
        cmd.run()

        commit_data = {}
        for line in cmd.stdout():
            key = line.split(' ')[0]
            m = re_sha.match(key)
            if m:
                commit_data = {
                    'sha': key
                }
            elif key in [
                'author',
                'author-mail',
                'author-time',
                'author-tz',
                'summary'
            ]:
                commit_data[key] = line[len(key)+1:]
            elif line.startswith('\t'):
                # assign the line to a commit
                # and create the Commit object if necessary
                commit = self.repo().get_commit(
                    commit_data.get('sha'),
                    # The following values are guaranteed to be present
                    # when a commit is seen for the first time,
                    # so they can be used for creating a Commit object.
                    author_name=commit_data.get('author'),
                    author_email=commit_data.get('author-mail'),
                    author_time=commit_data.get('author-time'),
                    author_tz=commit_data.get('author-tz'),
                    summary=commit_data.get('summary')
                )
                if len(line) > 1 or self.repo().config('count_empty_lines'):
                    author = commit.author()
                    if author not in self._authors:
                        self._authors.append(author)
                    author.add_lines(self, commit)
                    self.add_total_lines()
                    self.repo().add_total_lines()
```